# Player teleportation with item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to teleport a player when they use a certain item, let's say, a stick, name wand. When the player uses it they'll be teleported to a certain place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to give the item:

```
/give @p carrot_on_a_stick 1 0 {display:{Name:"Wand"}}
```

And add an objective to keep track of when people right click with (any) carrot on a stick:

```
/scoreboard objectives add UseCarrotStick stat.useItem.minecraft.carrot_on_a_stick
```

---

Then, repeating and in this order, have the following commands:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a remove HoldingWand
/scoreboard players tag @a add HoldingWand {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick",tag:{display:{Name:"Wand"}}}}
/tp @a[tag=HoldingWand,score_UseCarrotStick_min=1] X Y Z
/scoreboard players set @a UseCarrotStick 0
```

This gives anyone holding the wand a "HoldingWand" tag, then teleports anyone who has both a UseCarrotStick score of >=1 and the Holdingwand tag to X Y Z (to be replaced).

The first command is needed so that people who deselect the wand have the tag removed, and the last command is needed so that people are only teleported once per right click.

Comment: As a minor change, you can include only relevant players for the first in the set of commands (`/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=HoldingWand] remove HoldingWand`). Most commands are processed multiple times, equal to the number of targets obtained by selector. By including all players, `/scoreboard` is processed that many times even if only one player had the tag to remove. The same could be done for the last command (`/scoreboard players set @a[score_UseCarrotStick_min=1] UseCarrotStick 0`). It doesn't change the outcome but could be more performant.

Comment: So, I would have those last 4 on a clock, right?

Comment: @Monkeymaster Yep

Comment: I mean loads, oops